# indexing DataFrame pandas with pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file text with this format :

```
            Value_1     Value_2     Value_3     Value_4     Value_5
10  MSX 0.40748157  0.223845099 0.14417411  0.434948943 0.804686917
20  MSX 0.679787708 0.669394102 0.09966376  0.295964602 0.741914305
30  MSX 0.746162656 0.325330912 0.739320885 0.999178387 0.492413352
40  MSX 0.320922967 0.015966342 0.599784939 0.621426555 0.393276648
50  MSX 0.306445206 0.412270302 0.18820778  0.605985775 0.21907484
60  MSX 0.238848223 0.188215196 0.546380095 0.683780446 0.868291677
70  MSX 0.181441931 0.868270404 0.483950835 0.398810737 0.874501167
80  MSX 0.559737008 0.991398039 0.737921625 0.998737594 0.033864231
90  MSX 0.648728689 0.832948225 0.558207809 0.712151967 0.11245818
100 MSX 0.467005098 0.378185352 0.347756793 0.098410037 0.189492058
```

I read this file with pandas.read_csv like this :

```
import pandas

db = "data.txt"

a = pandas.read_csv(db, sep='\t')
```

Il would like to get value for line 40 and column Value_3 for example.

When I use :

```
a["Value_3"]
```

I have all column values for Value_3 :

```
>>> a["Value_3"]
    10   MSX    0.144174
    20   MSX    0.099664
    30   MSX    0.739321
    40   MSX    0.599785
    50   MSX    0.188208
    60   MSX    0.546380
    70   MSX    0.483951
    80   MSX    0.737922
    90   MSX    0.558208
    100  MSX    0.347757
    Name: Value_3
```

When I use a["40", "Value_3"] I have this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    a["40","Value_3"]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1704, in __getitem__
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 474, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 827, in get
    _, block = self._find_block(item)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 941, in _find_block
    self._check_have(item)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 948, in _check_have
    raise KeyError('no item named %s' % str(item))
KeyError: "no item named ('40', 'Value_3')"
```

Who can help me please ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is very well documented [Advanced indexing with hierarchical index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index).

Demo:

```
In [455]: df.loc[(slice(10,20), slice('MSX')), :]
Out[455]:
         Value_1   Value_2   Value_3   Value_4   Value_5
10 MSX  0.407482  0.223845  0.144174  0.434949  0.804687
20 MSX  0.679788  0.669394  0.099664  0.295965  0.741914
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but with my version of panda(0.09.0) loc is not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you get `MultiIndex`, for selecting is possible use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100], ['MSX']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx[40,'MSX'],'Value_3'])
0.599784939
```

---

```
print (df.loc[(40,'MSX'),'Value_3'])
0.599784939
```

You can also [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for set index names and convert index to columns:

```
df = df.rename_axis(['a','b']).reset_index(level=1)
print (df)
       b   Value_1   Value_2   Value_3   Value_4   Value_5
a                                                         
10   MSX  0.407482  0.223845  0.144174  0.434949  0.804687
20   MSX  0.679788  0.669394  0.099664  0.295965  0.741914
30   MSX  0.746163  0.325331  0.739321  0.999178  0.492413
40   MSX  0.320923  0.015966  0.599785  0.621427  0.393277
50   MSX  0.306445  0.412270  0.188208  0.605986  0.219075
60   MSX  0.238848  0.188215  0.546380  0.683780  0.868292
70   MSX  0.181442  0.868270  0.483951  0.398811  0.874501
80   MSX  0.559737  0.991398  0.737922  0.998738  0.033864
90   MSX  0.648729  0.832948  0.558208  0.712152  0.112458
100  MSX  0.467005  0.378185  0.347757  0.098410  0.189492

print (df.loc[40, 'Value_3'])
0.599784939
```

Or:

```
df = df.rename_axis(['a','b']).reset_index()
print (df)
     a    b   Value_1   Value_2   Value_3   Value_4   Value_5
0   10  MSX  0.407482  0.223845  0.144174  0.434949  0.804687
1   20  MSX  0.679788  0.669394  0.099664  0.295965  0.741914
2   30  MSX  0.746163  0.325331  0.739321  0.999178  0.492413
3   40  MSX  0.320923  0.015966  0.599785  0.621427  0.393277
4   50  MSX  0.306445  0.412270  0.188208  0.605986  0.219075
5   60  MSX  0.238848  0.188215  0.546380  0.683780  0.868292
6   70  MSX  0.181442  0.868270  0.483951  0.398811  0.874501
7   80  MSX  0.559737  0.991398  0.737922  0.998738  0.033864
8   90  MSX  0.648729  0.832948  0.558208  0.712152  0.112458
9  100  MSX  0.467005  0.378185  0.347757  0.098410  0.189492

print (df.loc[3, 'Value_3'])
0.599784939
```

EDIT:

Or if `index` is not `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df.index)
Index(['10 MSX', '20 MSX', '30 MSX', '40 MSX', '50 MSX', '60 MSX', '70 MSX',
       '80 MSX', '90 MSX', '100 MSX'],
      dtype='object')

print (df.loc['40 MSX', 'Value_3'])
0.599784939
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I use pandas version 0.09.0 and loc is not implemented, I can not upgrade panda version because i am not administrator of my computer.

Comment: I am not sure, but in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.09.0/) is not your version, last is `0.12.0`. So I have no idea how is possible select in your version. And last version is `0.19.2`, so recommend upgrade, but I understand sometimes it is not easy. But if `df = df.reset_index(level=1)` it should works.

Comment: @nekcorp, it's definitely time to upgrade! [0.9.0](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/release.html#id42) is almost 5 year old! Each new Pandas version adds a lot of nice features and fixes a lot of bugs.

Comment: Yes I know, but i am not responsable in my compagny and I can not upgrade software as i wish. I will use my computer with the last version of pandas. Thanks a lot for your answers.